# Android RelativeLayout margin

Tags: android, android-layout, margin, android-relativelayout

I have following XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@layout/light_list_item_border"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
   android:id="@+id/light_list_item_lightdim_button"
   android:layout_width="75dp"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:background="@drawable/button_on"
   android:text="@string/button_on"
   android:textColor="@color/white" 
   android:layout_margin="5dp"
   />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/light_list_item_lightrgb_label"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/light_list_item_lightdim_button"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/light_list_item_lightdim_button"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:text="@+id/label"
   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
   android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/light_list_item_lightrgb_labelSzene"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/light_list_item_lightdim_button"
   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
   android:text="@+id/label"
   android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:textSize="15sp" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/Button01"
   android:layout_width="75dp"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/light_list_item_lightdim_button"
   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/button_on"
   android:text="@string/button_add"
   android:textColor="@color/white" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

but for any case:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
```

of the 2nd button is 'ignored'?

Here you can see my Problem: the buttons labeled with a "+" should have a margin of 5 to the bottom border.

I have tried `android:paddingBottom` as well, but doesn't succeeded
[image: Screenshoot]

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think we need to see your "@layout/light_list_item_border" to be able to solve this. But for this problem, wouldnt it be easier to put padding on the relative layout itself, and skip all the margins?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@layout/light_list_item_border"
android:padding="5dp">
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want some space between layout and its content try providing a padding property to the relative layout itself say 5dp and remove unnecessary margin properties.

Answer (score 3):

just add this after button in xml

```
<View
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="5dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/plusbuttonid" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove these two lines:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
```

Add

```
android:layout_margin="5dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Remove the property: 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

And your new code for 2nd button looks like:

```
 <Button 
 android:id="@+id/Button01"  
 android:layout_width="75dp"  
 android:layout_height="40dp"   
 android:layout_below="@+id/light_list_item_lightdim_button"   
 android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"   
 android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
 android:background="@drawable/button_on"   
 android:text="@string/button_add"    android:textColor="@color/white"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

In values/dimens.xml file you can set margins.

```
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```